# Selenium vs Celerity?

Tags: tdd, selenium, bdd, watir, celerity

Isn't Selenium better than Celerity when it comes to testing web sites cause real browsers like Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Internet Explorer could be used so that we know our website is compatible with each of them.

So if I use Celerity (it's java browser), even if all tests pass, doesn't that mean my website could still be incompatible with our popular web browsers?

I know it's slower, but if we do not take that into account, isn't Celerity more error prone then?

Comment: Reading over Celerity web site it seams like that it is API comparable with Watir (which does use real browsers). So you could create tests that use Celerity for quick running tests (say on commit), and Watir for nightly/weekly slow running tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need speed, use [Celerity](http://celerity.rubyforge.org/). If you want tests executed in a real browser, use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Watir](http://watir.com/). Celerity emulates browser and Selenium and Watir drive real browsers. If your site is simple, Celerity should work fine. If there is a lot of JavaScript, maybe a real browser should be better.